# Bot crashes if collector doesnt get a correct answer

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I made a `&scramble` command that would basicly scramble a word and display it for people to guess, after 30 seconds it would stop accepting answers and say who got it right first, this part works fine but when no one gets it right, the bot simply crashes for not returning someone, giving the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'author' of undefined`

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'scramble',
    execute(message, args) {
        const Discord = require('discord.js')
        let givenword = args.slice(0).join(" ");
        
        function scramble(givenword) {
            var word= givenword.split("")
            n = word.length

            for(var i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
                var tmp = word[i];
                word[i] = word[j]
                word[j] = tmp;
            }
            return word.join("")
        }
       scrambledword = scramble(givenword)

       const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
       .setTitle('Scramble time!')
       .setColor("RANDOM")
       .setDescription("The word is: " + scrambledword)
       .setFooter('You have 30 seconds to try and guess it, the first person to answer correctly ')
         message.channel.send({embed});
         message.delete()

      
         const filter = m => m.content.includes(givenword)
       const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { time: 30000 });
       
       collector.on('collect', m => {
            console.log(`Collected ${m.content}`);
       });
       
       collector.on('end', collected => {
        if (collected.length <= 0) {
                message.channel.send('Sadly it seems like no one has guessed the answer right... The word was ' + givenword + "!")
            } else {
                message.channel.send(`${collected.first().author} got the correct answer first! The answer was ${givenword}`);
            }
           console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
       });
        


   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at [discord.js's docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) shows that the property [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)`#length` can't be equal or less than `0`, since it doesn't exist. However, you can still convert it with [`Collection#array()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=array) or [`Collection#keyArray()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=keyArray). I personally prefer the second option because we don't need the rest of the data here.

```js
collector.on('end', collected => {
  if (collected.keyArray().length <= 0) {
    message.channel.send('Sadly it seems like no one has guessed the answer right... The word was ' + givenword + "!")
  } else {
    message.channel.send(`${collected.first().author} got the correct answer first! The answer was ${givenword}`);
  }
  console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
});
```